# Memory leak in AFNetworking Cache images in IOS

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, afnetworking

I just moved from ASIHTTP to AFNetworking library. I am also using SDURLCache library from Olivier Poitrey and Peter Steinberg. I want to cache all the images that I gonna use in my application. For these, I tried this:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        for(NSURLRequest *imageRequest in imageRequestArray){
            AFURLConnectionOperation *operation2 = [[[AFURLConnectionOperation alloc] initWithRequest:imageRequest] autorelease];
            [queue addOperation: operation2];
            [operation2 waitUntilFinished];
}
```

And when I need to show images, I am doing this for each image:

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[cat imagePath]];
        NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30.0];


        AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:imageRequest 
                                                                                  imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                                                                             cacheName:@"nscache"
                                                                                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                                                                                   //NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
                                                                                                   imageView.alpha = 0.0;
                                                                                                   [imageView setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                                                                                   [UIView beginAnimations:@"ToggleViews" context:nil];
                                                                                                   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];                
                                                                                                   imageView.alpha = 1.0;
                                                                                                   [UIView commitAnimations];
                                                                                               }
                                                                                               failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){}
                                              ];
        [operation start];
```

After a while, application gives memory warning, then shuts down. For that, I did the following:

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
NSLog(@"Memory Warning...");
}
```

It clears the cache(what I don't what) but after a while, application closes again.

What should I do for that?

Comment: I believe I am having a similar problem, when I checked with Instruments the memory usage of my app keeps going up until it hits about 200megs then the app is terminated due to a memory warning, I am attempting to track the problem down, there doesn't appear to be any leaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely caused because ARC doesn't automatically get set up on queues or on background threads. I had the same issue and solved it with the following article:

https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/memory-leaks-with-arc/